# exporting lists from live to development

Tags: 2010, list, development

Ive created a small equipment calibration system in sp2010 using 2 lists that are linked.  Ive made some customisations using sp developer.  The team have now requested that the equipment owners are emailed when the item needs recalibrating.  I need to export the lists from our live system and put them into my development environment so i can create the timer job and test that it works.  How can i export the site that these lists reside in so i can write my timer job and test?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Collaboration sites (e.g. Team Site, Group Work Site, etc.) - those not having Pages library, but rather Site Pages to store pages (also work with Publishing site definitions, but you need to manually append to _/layouts/savetmpl.aspx), you could easily try via Site Settings  - Save as Template (make sure you check the Include Content option) which in Galleries would create a new .stp file containing the content of the site.

Click on it to download it, copy it onto the new location in the site collection Gallery, upload and create the new site using this new Template which you shall find in the Create Site dialog. See more here on this procedure http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/save-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template-HA101782501.aspx